# hashing from php script to mySql works on localhost but not web server?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, php-password-hash

I am trying to hash a password and store it in a mySql database. When storing with localhost this was fine, now I have moved to server the hashing method prevents the whole thing from working. If I remove the hashing code it saves just fine but I wish to hash the passwords. Seems strange as the same code works fine locally and the web based code connects to Sql fine. I have tried various different ways to hash, as soon as I try any all I get is

"2013-10-15 22:37:07.915 UsernameAndPasswordwithphp[20249:a0b] Response from server = "

rather than

"2013-10-15 22:54:53.750 UsernameAndPasswordwithphp[21323:a0b] Response from server = Connection established
Database selected"

I am running php 5.5.3

many thanks in advance!

here is my code

```
<?php
//session_start()


$host = ""; 
$user = ""; 
$pass = ""; 
$db = "";

$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$r) {
    echo "Could not connect to server\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "Connection established\n"; 
}

$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);

if (!$r2) {
    echo "Cannot select database\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
} else {
    echo "Database selected\n";
}


$usernameFromApp = $_GET["f1"];
$nameFromApp = $_GET["f2"];
$passwordFromApp = $_GET["f3"];



 $timeTarget = 0.2; 
 $cost = 9;
 do {
     $cost++;
     $start = microtime(true);
     password_hash($passwordFromApp, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
     $end = microtime(true);
 } while (($end - $start) < $timeTarget);
 $hash = password_hash($passwordFromApp, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);

 echo "Appropriate Cost Found: " . $cost . "\n";
 echo $hash."\n";




$name = $_GET["f2"];

$username = $_GET["f1"];

$password = $hash;

//$password = $_GET["f3"];

$query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('', '$name','$username','$password')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));

mysql_close();


?>
```

Comment: I'd be more worried about the gaping wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities in your code... Plus, I fail to see what your while() loop is accomplishing other than burning electricity. You're not capturing the generated hash, you're just generating the SAME hash over and over... then generate it again once the loop's completed. this means the loop's utterly pointless as anything other than a time waster. you might as well save a few pennies of power bill and just have `sleep($time)` in there.

Comment: Are your host, user, pass & db empty on purpose??

Comment: what php version is on server? have you turned on all error displaying?

Comment: Marc I am new to coding so forgive errors, That code came from http://uk3.php.net/password_hash  yes gavin they are, I deleted them for upload. php version is I am running php 5.5.3 (thats what I got from running "<?php phpinfo() ?>" and no I didnt know about all error displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have PHP 5.5 on your server as well? Have you double checked this with `phpinfo()`?

If so, remove the `while` loop in your code first. This is from the manual and I know the code, but it's meant to bench how much cost your server can handle in a specific time window. You don't need this in production. Bench it once and set the cost (or simply stick to the default which is good enough).

Check your database credentials, create a new file and debug only the database connection first. It seems like that this is the problem you are facing. Make sure to set `error_reporting(-1)` and `ini_set("display_errors", true)`, that should ensure that you get a response from your script if something goes wrong.

Also note that `mysql` is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and you should definitely not use it anymore, use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Validate any and all user input, never trust anything!

Use prepared statements for your SQL (supported by `mysqli` and `PDO`).

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will take a look tomorrow

Comment: All was fine apart from Server. The server only runs 5.3 something. Thank you for your help

Comment: I guessed so. PHP 5.5 has some very very nice features but most hosting providers don't update that fast. Glad to hear that I was from help.

Comment: Yes you were, thank you again. The server only runs 5.3.27 so I cant even use password_compat. bit of a nightmare!